# arcpy.mapping ListLayers to arcpy.mp listLayers

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, attributeerror

I am working on updating a Python 2 script (arcpy.mapping) to a Python 3 script (arcpy.mp).

I've successfully updated the following:

```
aprxFile=r"G:\usr\Drinking Water Programs\Monroe 2023-02\Maps\ProMap.aprx" #aprx document
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
aprx = Map.ArcGISProject(aprxFile)
layout = aprx.listLayouts('DWP_Maps_5')[0]
noteStat = layout.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT","Note_statistic")[0]
noteStat.text = "Mapped value is the average for the "+unit
noteTreat = layout.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT", "Note_treated")[0]
noteTreat.text = "Treated samples not mapped"
noteAny = layout.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT", "Note_any_sample")[0]
noteAny.text = " "
notePerDist = layout.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT", "Note_Distribution_per_unit")[0]
notePerDist.text = " "
notePerNum = layout.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT", "Note_Numbers_per_unit")[0]
notePerNum.text = " "
```

The next part not so successfully:

```
dfList = aprx.listMaps(aprx)
baseMCD1 = dfList.listLayers("MCD_light") #new code
baseMCD2 = Map.listLayers(aprx,"MCD_medium",dfList[0])[0] #old code
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) In  [37]: Line 84:
>     baseMCD1 = dfList.listLayers("MCD_light")
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'listLayers'

Comment: You are trying to use `arcpy.mapping` sytax with `arcpy.mp`.  For example, `aprx.listMaps(aprx)` isn't going to return any results.  Even after you change the line to `dfList = aprx.listMaps()`, the next line of code still won't work because `listMaps()` returns a Python list of Maps in the APRX, and Python lists have no `listLayers` method, hence the error.  You need to either select a map from the Python list or iterate over the whole list and call retrieve the layers of the individual Map objects.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to listLayers on the list object of maps.  You need to select a map from that list.

Example:

```
dfList = aprx.listMaps()[0] #First map in list
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included your imports but, in any event, I think you will be writing more readable code if you replace:

```
aprx = Map.ArcGISProject(aprxFile)
```

with:

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprxFile)
```